# Need to repeat and calculate values in a single Select statement

Tags: sql, select, record, repeat

I hope that someone can help me with my issue. I need to create in a single SELECT statement (the system that we use has some pivot tables in Excel that handle one single SELECT) the following:

I have a INL (Invoice Lines) table, that has a lot of fields, but the important one is the date.

```
INL_ID    DATE
  19    2004-03-15 00:00:00.000
  20    2004-03-15 00:00:00.000
  21    2004-03-15 00:00:00.000
  22    2004-03-16 00:00:00.000
  23    2004-03-16 00:00:00.000
  24    2004-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

Now, I also have a ILD (Invoice Line Details) that are related by an ID field to the INL table. From the second table I will need to use the scu_qty field to "repeat" values from the first one in my results sheet.

The ILD table values that we need are:

```
INL_ID    scu_qty
19          1
20          1
21          1
22          4
23          4
```

Now, with the scu_qty I need to repeat the value of the first table and also add one day each record, the scu_qty is the quantity of days of the services that we sell in the ILD table.

So I need to get something like (i'm going to show the INL_ID 22 that you can see has a value different of 1 in the SCU_QTY). The results of the select has to give me something like:

```
INL_ID  DATE
22  2004-03-15  0:00:00
22  2004-03-16  0:00:00
22  2004-03-17  0:00:00
22  2004-03-18  0:00:00
```

In this information I only wrote the fields that need to be repeated and calculated, of course I will need more fields, but will be repeated from the INL table, so I don't put them so you don't get confused.

I hope that someone can help me with this, it's very important for us this report. Thanks a lot in advance

(Sorry for my English, that isn't my first language)

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT INL_ID, scu_qty, CalculatedDATE ...  
FROM INL  
INNER JOIN ILD ON ...  
INNER JOIN SequenceTable ON SequenceTable.seqNo <= ILD.scu_qty
ORDER BY INL_ID, SequenceTable.seqNo
```

Depending on your SQL flavour you will need to lookup date manipulation functions to do
`CalculatedDATE = {INL.DATE + SequenceTable.seqNo (days)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
select INL.INL_ID, `DATE`
from 
    INL
    inner join
    ILD on INL.INL_ID = ILD.INL_ID
    inner join (
        select 1 as qty union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    ) s on s.qty <= ILD.scu_qty
order by INL.INL_ID
```

In instead of that subselect you will need a table if quantity is a bit bigger. Or tell what is your RDBMS and there can be an easier way.